# How to achieve Tramo/Seats seasonaly analysis with regressos in statsmodels?

Tags: python, statsmodels, eviews, gretl

I frequently used Eviews for econometric analysis, and would like to move on to Python for some automatic work. Now I wonder how can I achieve Tramo/Seats seasonaly analysis with regressors in statsmodels?

To be specific, I have a monthly series of economic data (Y), but it suffer some known seasonal effect like spring-festival-effect, which I have quantified them and summarized as another series (X). In Eviews, I clicked Y serie, then proc -> Seasonal Adjustment -> Tramo/Seats..., in the pop-up windows, other than Tramo/Seats Tab, you have Regressors Tab, which you can add `X` serie as seasonal component or separate additional component, and then OK, you can got the perfect seasonal adjusted values.

In statsmodels, I used `sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis` Function:

```
sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(Y, exog = X, forecast_years = 0, prefer_x13 = True)
```

But the result is far from satisfying. It seems the `exog = X` options has no effect at all. The results both with or without `exog = X` option resemble that from the Eviews Tramo/Seats analysis without indicating `X` as seasonal component as regressor.

Can anyone tell me why?

P.S I checked gretl tramo/seats analysis. It does not have adding regressors functions neither.